# Productive use for old SO-DIMMs?

Tags: memory, hardware

Being the local geek, friends and family turn to me for upgrading RAM in their computers. They provide the new sticks and I keep the old ones. As such, I have accumulated quite the collection of DDR3 SODIMMs, consisting of pairs of 1GB and 2GB sticks.

Over the years I've made fishing lures, tie clips and other "cute" things. Unfortunately I haven't found a motherboard with 16 SO-DIMM slots. I'm hoping for a productive use for these sticks. Something to benefit my 2008 Mac Pro or another device on my network.

Preferably the uses would be something other than vaporware products and something I might actually purchase, PCIe based or as a stand-alone thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could sell them on eBay. Some people have 5 to 10 year old computers that take smaller RAM upgrades.